# How do i implement collision with "player" to "walls"?

Tags: c#, collision-detection

I've made a simple game and added collisions so my player would not go outside the window, it worked and i wanted to make some walls and make the collision for them too but it did not work / was really buggy. 
Is there a way and what is it to stop "player" from going though walls?

Movement code:

```
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            left = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            right = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            up = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            down = true;
        }
    }


    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        #region Stop controls
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            left = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            right = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            up = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            down = false;
        }
    }
```

My outside wall collision:

```
            if (right == true)
        {
            if (player.Left >= level.Width - player.Width)
            {
                player.Left = level.Width - player.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                player.Left += speed;
            }
        }

        if (left == true)
        {
            if (player.Left <= level.Left)
            {
                player.Left = level.Left;
            }
            else
            {
                player.Left -= speed;
            }
        }

        if (up == true)
        {
            if(player.Top <= level.Top)
            {
                player.Top = level.Top;
            }
            else
            {
                player.Top -= speed;
            }
        }

        if (down == true)
        {
            if (player.Top >= level.Bottom - player.Height)
            {
                player.Top = level.Bottom - player.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                player.Top += speed;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I read it as though currently you use Integer values to determine the players coordinates as well as the boundaries of the outer walls.

What you could do to achieve a form of wall is to use a 2D array.

An array within an array so to speak, to mimic a coordinate system.

Then you could make each of those array coordinates hold a "CellInformation" object.

The CellInformation object would know if it was walkable or not, meaning that for example, assuming the player is at coordinate (4,4) and tries to move left to (3,4), he would pick array 4 within array 3, take the object from there and ask it if it's walkable, if it is, the player sets his new coordinates to (3,4).

You could then also add a ton of other information to each cell, for example if it's wooden material, water, lava, dirt, a forest area, if there's enemies present and so on.

More info on 2D arrays: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you mean a some sort of a grid right?
But would the "player" move freely without any "grid" like restrictions?

Comment: And my player would be only 1 pixel wide and 1 pixel tall. No?

Comment: Yes it would work as a grid.

Are you making this purely in C# or inside a game engine?

If you make it purely in C# and you only set the players location with variables, then there would be no restrictions other than the ones you set.

You can define the outer parts of the grid as the outer boundary walls. This along with the settings you define for each cell would then decide where the player can walk, and as such, his movement restrictions.

Comment: Yes I'm making this in c#. Should I make it in some other engine? Or use xna/monoGame that I have 0 experience in? I'm just looking to make a simple working platformer sort of game.

Comment: It really depends what the end goal you have in mind is.

If you just wish to make a small experimental console game, what you're doing seems fine.

If C# has to be your language and you'd like to use an engine to more easily expand and keep an overview of the game, I'd personally use Unity as an engine to make a game, regardless of it being 2D or 3D.

Keep in mind you'd have to learn how to use the engine as well though, and it would be less orientated towards learning basic programming and more towards working with the given engine/framework.

Comment: A side note, I'm not familiar with  xna/monoGame, so can't really answer regarding them.